# How can i check the current usage of ram with Node.js? (Discord.js Bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a command called _ram it should display the current usage of the bots ram. I already tried these things:

```
${client.performance.memory} //(Says memory is not defined)
${window.performance.memory} //(Window is not defined)
```

Is there a working way how to display it?

Comment: You may want to tag your question with [\[electron\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/electron) as well, as it has its own APIs to query the actual total memory use, and in more ways than what's possible with Node.js only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to know how much memory your Node.js process is using, you can query:

```
process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
```

It will output the memory used by your process in bytes. It won't show the real memory used by Node.js, as in that case you also need to take into account Node.js garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use: `process.memoryUsage()` which returns an object describing the memory usage of the process in bytes.

```
{
  rss: 4935680,
  heapTotal: 1826816,
  heapUsed: 650472,
  external: 49879
}
```

> `heapTotal` and `heapUsed` refer to V8's memory usage. `external` refers to
>   the memory usage of C++ objects bound to JavaScript objects managed by
>   V8. `rss`, Resident Set Size, is the amount of space occupied in the
>   main memory device (that is a subset of the total allocated memory)
>   for the process, which includes the heap, code segment and stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
var os = require('os');

var usedMemory = os.totalmem() -os.freemem(), totalMemory = os.totalmem();

var  getpercentage = 
  ((usedMemory/totalMemory) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%'

console.log("Memory used in GB", (usedMemory/ Math.pow(1024, 3)).toFixed(2))
console.log("Used memory" , getpercentage);
```